# How to separate middleware in feathers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, feathersjs

I use to upload files a multer library with feathers. I try to separate logic from code and I want put upload code not in a index.js but in my case in pdf.js in middleware directory.

Below is my works index.js:

```
'use strict';

const pdf = require('./pdf');
const record = require('./record');
const records = require('./records');

const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const notFound = require('./not-found-handler');
const logger = require('./logger');

const uploadPdf = require('./upload-pdf');

module.exports = function() {
  // Add your custom middleware here. Remember, that
  // just like Express the order matters, so error
  // handling middleware should go last.

  const app = this;

  app.use('/rekord/:id.html', record(app));
  app.use('/rekordy.html', records(app));
  app.use('/pdf/:id', uploadPdf.single('file'), pdf(app));

  app.use(notFound());
  app.use(logger(app));
  app.use(handler());
};
```

Here is upload-pdf.js file:

```
  var multer  = require('multer')

  var storagePdf = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'public/pdf',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {

      var id = req.params.id

      cb(null, id+'.pdf')
    }
  });

  module.exports = multer({
      storage: storagePdf,
      fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'application/pdf') {
          return cb(null, false, new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'));
        }
      cb(null, true);
     }
     });
```

And pdf.js file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.file) {
      return res.end('Thank you for the file');
    }
    return res.end('false');

    next();

  };
};
```

I would like to combine upload-pdf.js and pdf.js into one file

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly Feathers specific, just as with any other Express application you can put the code into their own modules:

```
'use strict';

const pdf = require('./pdf');
const record = require('./record');
const records = require('./records');

const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const notFound = require('./not-found-handler');
const logger = require('./logger');

module.exports = function() {
  // Add your custom middleware here. Remember, that
  // just like Express the order matters, so error
  // handling middleware should go last.

  const app = this;

  app.use('/rekord/:id.html', record(app));
  app.use('/rekordy.html', records(app));
  app.use('/pdf/:id', pdf.upload.single('file'), pdf.process(app));

  app.use(notFound());
  app.use(logger(app));
  app.use(handler());
};
```

In `pdf.js`:

```
'use strict';

var multer = require('multer')

var storagePdf = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'public/pdf',
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {

    var id = req.params.id

    cb(null, id + '.pdf')
  }
});

exports.upload = multer({
  storage: storagePdf,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype !== 'application/pdf') {
      return cb(null, false, new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
  }
});

exports.process = function(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.file) {
      return res.end('Thank you for the file');
    }
    return res.end('false');

    next();
  };
};
```

The [NodeJS module system docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html) are quite helpful to learn how it all fits together.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your answer is helpful. Is it possible to put all in one file so That there was no need use: `const upload Pdf = require ('./ upload-pdf')`?

Comment: Wouldn't that be exactly what you were doing before?

Comment: Maybe is it but my code not works. Your code works properly but you include two file: `const pdf = require ('./ pdf')` and `const uploadPdf = require ('./ upload-pdf');` I would like to it put into one file . Is it possible? Can you show me other example?

Comment: `const pdf = require ('./ pdf')` was in your original code. Since it doesn't seem to be used anywhere it can probably just be removed.

Comment: In the example given by you is: `app.use('/pdf/:id', uploadPdf.single('file'), pdf(app));` it seems that it is needed. I updated my question,

Comment: can you help me again?

Comment: As the Node module examples showed you can also add properties to the `exports` property to export multiple methods. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is what I meant. It works perfectly now. Excellently! Thank you Daff